# Is there a way to merge a non-Google-Apps Google Voice account with a Google Apps account?

Tags: google-workspace, google-account, google-voice

I have a Google Voice account that I created before it was available on Google Apps.  I recently created a Google Apps account and maintain my e-mail as ben@mydomain.com.

Is there a process that exists for merging my Google Voice account into my apps account so that I don't have to switch accounts to use Google Voice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to merge your Google Voice account with your Google Apps account and retain the data.

You can however request that your Google Voice number gets transferred to your Google Apps account.

[See this Google article for full details](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182173)